# Issue with changing the colour of textview - android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I have 2 text views in my fragment. When opening of the fragment 1st text view will be in red(#e92624). When pressed 2nd text view then 1st view should be black(#D8000000) and 2nd text view should turn to red.

in my onCreate I have,

```
mQuickReturnViewPas.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e92624"));

        if (selectedView != null)
            mQuickReturnViewPas.setBackgroundColor(Color
                    .parseColor("#D8000000"));
```

Outside onCreate I have,

```
                      mQuickReturnViewPas
                        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                if (selectedView != null)
                                    selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                            .parseColor("#D8000000"));

                                // set selectedView to be current selected view
                                selectedView = (TextView) v;

                                // change selected view to be red
                                selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                        .parseColor("#e92624"));

                            }

                        });

                mQuickReturnViewRic
                        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                if (selectedView != null)
                                    selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                            .parseColor("#D8000000"));

                                // set selectedView to be current selected view
                                selectedView = (TextView) v;

                                // change selected view to be red
                                selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                        .parseColor("#e92624"));
                            }

                        });
            }
```

With this code, if I press the 2nd text view it turns to red but 1st text view stays in red(doesn't change to black).  What is the change I should make in my `onCreate` method to achieve this task?

Comment: In onClick you should change the color of your first text view not in onCreate.

Comment: Yes, answer1 will do it for you. You were missing this statement 
 other_textView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                                .parseColor("#D8000000"));

Comment: @Kesh1234 My bad I missed it, that is really working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your methods like this

```
    mQuickReturnViewPas
                            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    if (selectedView != null)
                                        selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                                .parseColor("#D8000000"));

                                    // set selectedView to be current selected view
                                    selectedView = (TextView) v;

                                    // change selected view to be red
                                    selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                            .parseColor("#e92624"));
                                   // change non-selected view to be black
                                            mQuickReturnViewRic.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                                .parseColor("#D8000000"));



                                }

                            });

                    mQuickReturnViewRic
                            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                    if (selectedView != null)
                                        selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                                .parseColor("#D8000000"));

                                    // set selectedView to be current selected view
                                    selectedView = (TextView) v;

                                    // change selected view to be red
                                    selectedView.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                            .parseColor("#e92624"));
                                  // change non-selected view to be black
                               mQuickReturnViewPas.setBackgroundColor(Color
                                                    .parseColor("#D8000000"));
                                }

                            });
```